# Strange error registering an old ActiveX control

Tags: .net, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, activex

We're using the CGridCtrl (grid32.ocx) in some of our old legacy MFC applications and recently upgraded from .NET 4.0 to 4.5.1, using VS2012. Now our applications using this grid control are no longer working. When debugging I get assert fails from occcont.cpp line 925. I found a Microsoft article for line 926 ([link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949107)) which I figure is close enough that indicates it's failing to register the ActiveX control. I manually registered it with regsvr32.exe, got a success, but the applications still fail.

The strange part is that it only fails when **run as Administrator** -- when run normally without admin privileges there are no issues at all. I'm not really sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: Can this [solution](http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/assert-in-occcont-cpp-926-colecontrolcontainer-filllistsitesorwnds/) help you?

Comment: try run regsvr32 as administrator and see if the registration still fails. Remember to regsvr32 /u to remove your existing registration, which is probably registered to HKCU. registering the ActiveX should be the job of your installer.

Comment: Are you running under Vista?  That control is [no longer supported](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-system/grid32ocx-not-correctly-registered/e1252672-c546-40ed-8932-72d4fbf2f456) under Vista and perhaps Win7.

Comment: Jacob - thanks but I already have it running as apartment threaded.

Comment: Sheng - Yes you're right I had forgotten to unregister it first, and it was in HKCU as you guessed. If you want to put this into an answer I will mark it as complete. Now I guess I'll need to find out why the installer is not registering it correctly...